# Black out screen in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, black-screen-of-death

When i work on my windows machine, am getting a black screen in regular intervals.

What should I do? Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it while you're working or after it's idle for a little while?

Comment: while working in Freescale's code warrior tool (both eclipse based and classic one )

Comment: How long does it stay black? Does it come back on again? Is the plug for the monitor falling out?

Comment: when i do a build in code warrior version 3.0 , the black out happens and it stays for the whole compilation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

There might be lot of issue causing this, are you getting any error or just getting Black Screen?

Try changing your RAM slot OR use chkdsk tool it will resolve issue if any file type corrupted.

Good Luck :)

Comment: can you little bit explain more about the chkdsk tool?